# Why do we use exponents in characteristic function

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, generating-functions, characteristic-functions

A student who is attending probability 101, learned about normal distribution and generating functions recently.

We are given a "generating function" as follows:
$$G(t)=<e^{itx}>=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{itx}p(x)dx$$

And we are asked to explain the following:
1) why is there an exponent
2) why do we use the imaginary unit

As I am really new to probability, few stuff that I knew is the function is a characteristic function, and it somehow related to Fourier transform (which I haven't learned yet). Could someone show me what to search for, or try to explain the above questions? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific exponent ensures that the characteristic function of a distribution always exists as well as having some nice properties.
It is of course possible to take another exponent such as the moment generating function
$$
M_X(t) = E[e^{tX}]
$$
Which is not guaranteed to exist. Take for example the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).

The exponent also guarantees nice properties of the characteristic function ([Properties on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Properties)).
One in particular, is that the characteristic function is bounded
$$
|\varphi_X(t)| \leq 1
$$

The Fourier transform is the complex conjugate of the characteristic function.